# not able to see the website uploaded in aws s3 bucket

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

I have build my angular project using `ng build` and created a minified dist folder.
after that, I uploaded the content of the folder to the bucket.

Now when I see the URL, and if I click on network, I can see all the content of dist folder, means everything what it need is there, but still not able to view the web page.
I am attaching a screenshot.
[image]

As you can see, I am not getting any error or anything but still it is not working. why?

Comment: what is your lading page ?

Comment: The link what you shared is working for me

Answer (score 1):

The link what you have shared in chat is working for me. Better clear your cache. or check any proxy. Website is bit slow try to enable cloudfront for better performance.

Comment: For me, clearing cache is not working. I did clear cache and hard reload. what more can I do?

Comment: check any proxy blocking

Comment: how to check that?